# Ag Grid column becomes left aligned when Check Box Selection is enabled on that column

Tags: angular, ag-grid

To get a clear view on what the problem is, take a look at the attached image

[image]

In the picture, the Assessment column is left-aligned. But in column definitions, I've set it to be center aligned.

Column definition for the grid.

```js
let colDefs = [
        {
            field: 'title',
            headerName: 'Assessment',
            checkboxSelection: true,
            headerCheckboxSelection: true,
            cellStyle: {
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        }, 
        {
            field: 'dna',
            headerName: 'DNA?',
            maxWidth: 60,
            cellStyle: {
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        }
]
```

If I set `checkboxSelection: false` it again becomes center aligned. So, this flag is causing ag-grid to render the Assessment column as left aligned.

How can I use `checkboxSelection` and also make the column center aligned?

N:B: I am using ag-grid version **23** with **Angular 9**

Comment: did you make any progress? I'm trying to solve a similar problem, I'm using cellRenderer function to render multiples checkboxes by row, and I'm also being unable to center align them

Comment: I don't remember exactly. But I think I resorted to using `display:flex` and `justify-content:center!important` inside for the `.ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell` CSS selector. But be careful. You may have to change all cell styles accordingly.